# Collecting metrics for your application

Tags: monitoring, graphite

Curious how people are integrating sending of metrics to graphite. It appears most are using a client (many available on statsd github) that sends to statsd which sends on to carbon.
My question is do you think it is ok to include this "cross cutting concern" as such directly into your code. What I am seeing is my application code has went from been nice and clean to now not so nice and clean with code to gather metrics intertwined with my business code.
Any thoughts?

Comment: I think the answers will vary depending on whether you are talking specifically about business metrics or system metrics. Can you clarify?

Comment: I am talking about your companies applications which is the companies business.within these applications are people sending metrics and therefore making the code less clean\readible etc

Comment: I don't agree with you. It's like logging, when you're logging do you say you have less clean\readible code? no, the opposite, you can say that this code has some level of important information for the runtime. In my opinion logging is very crucial for live systems and also the "Metrics". Just look on the "Metrics" as you do with Logging. Also notice that there are several solutions which combine the logging with the metrics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do think that it's fine to include code to send business metrics in your application code. As @tomer-peled says in his comment, there is a close analogy with logging.

However I understand your reluctance to scatter this stuff around and possibly obfuscate the code. My approach in situations like this is to accept a certain amount of mess to begin with, then as more examples emerge I try to identify emergent structures which point to abstractions that would clean things up a bit.